# Working with workflows and populating lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

Hey all,
   I am currently building a workflow, i created a list (let say list A), when the user fills out the list (form) and clicks OK button the workflow kick starts. the first action of workflow should be populating all the fields(whatever filled by user) in the List A to List B (here list B has same columns as list A but some additional columns). How to built this action in workflow. Any thoughts are highly appreciated. Quite a newbie to Sharepoint, eager to learn more about it.

Suppose List A has name field, its being filled as XYZ, then workflow should be able to populate XYZ in same corresponding name field in List B. I hope I made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is whether you want to use Sharepoint Designer or a Visual Studio Workflow.

In Visual Studio you have the full Sharepoint object model galore to your hands - the sky is the limit.
In Sharepoint Designer you only have a limited set of Actions which enable you to do stuff. Let me explain a SPD solution.

You basically want this:

- List A

  - Field: Name
  - Field: Testing
  - Field: Age
- List B

  - Field: Name
  - Field: Country
  - Field: Age

So basically you could transfer Name and Age from A --> B upon creating a new item in list A.

In Sharepoint Designer you can just create a list workflow for list A, which automatically starts upon a new item in the list. When the workflow starts it just needs to get all the data you just entered in the form. So you can use the action **Set Workflow Variable** and set different variables (of the same name) to *Name*, *Testing*, and *Age* from the item.

You now would have the item's data as workflow variables.

The action **Create List Item** is next, here you can select a list, an item should be created in and set fields for that list item to your variables. So you could set workflow variable Name to the item's Name in List B, similarly the Age.